# Populating html input element from php

Tags: php, html

FX 54, PHP 7.0
I have an HTML input element into which I want to insert a value (which is a VARCHAR from a database via a php array).
The value is typically= Mode: SWITCHED OFF (note the spaces)
Inserting php into an input element thus:

```
<input id= "mod" name= "mod" value= <?= $otherSet["mod"] ?> readonly " onclick= "toserve(mod)">
```

then displays Mode: (and only this)

```
<?php $otherSet["mod"] ?>` outside of an input element displays   Mode: SWITCHED OFF   as it should.
<?php
$k= $otherSet[mod]; echo $otherSet[mod];    //echo is good
$k = 'Mode: SWITCHED OFF'; echo $k;         //echo is good
?>
```

$k in `<input....>` does not work.

I've tried every combination of quotes for variables mixed as above but the results are all the same
Keying the string into the webpage works.
AJAXing the dBase into the webpage onload works but is a horrible kludge.
So its not an  truncation problem.

The issue seems to concern the space(s) from php alone in the  element - if I remove the first space I then get    Mode: SWITCHED    etc.

BTW should I put ; at the end of the shortform style, e.g. $otherSet["mod"]; and should the array keys be quoted (it doesn't seem to make any difference in any scripts).

Comment: Take a look at the raw HTML generated by your output ("view source" in the browser).  You're omitting quotes around attributes which contain spaces and basically generating broken HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre missing `""` in `value` attribute. Change to:

```
value="<?= $otherSet["mod"] ?>"
```

Comment: Thank you both!<br>For any text without a contained space my original *does* work so for anybody else please take note.

Comment: Yes, it will work because some browsers can read it, but its not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id= "mod" name= "mod" value= <?= $otherSet["mod"] ?> readonly " onclick= "toserve(mod)">
```

to

```
<input id= "mod" name= "mod" value="<?= $otherSet['mod'] ?>" readonly onclick= "toserve(mod)" />
```